# How to send an email using command line?

Tags: command-line, bash, email

Here's what I have:

```
cat UserReport.txt | mail -s "TestSubject" "nospam@gmail.com"
```

It's a small file, much smaller than a picture so it should send almost instantly. Though I receive nothing. I installed `mailutils` but might have installed it incorrectly.

How can I send an email from a bash script?

Comment: That shoud work if the system runs an MTA. Does your system use sendmail, ssmtp, postfix, ...?

Comment: It's a 12.04 VM, if that tells you anything, and I have no clue what my company uses

Comment: Having mailutils installed is not sufficient. You need a MTA, as @Jan noticed. What do `ls -l $(which sendmail)` tells you? And `dpkg -S  $(which sendmail)`? what are you using to read and send email normally, and with which configuration? Please add this info to your question.

Comment: I am curious: what was the issue in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25849276/bash-script-issues-on-redhat-6-5 ?

Comment: [Useless use of `cat`](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#cat)

Answer (score 31):

First of all you need to install and configure Postfix to Use Gmail SMTP on Ubuntu.

Install all necessary packages:

```
$ sudo apt-get install postfix mailutils libsasl2-2 ca-certificates libsasl2-modules
```

If you do not have postfix installed before, postfix configuration wizard will ask you some questions. Just select your server as **Internet Site** and for FQDN use something like **mail.example.com**

Then open your ***postfix config file***:

```
$ sudo -H gedit /etc/postfix/main.cf
```

and add following lines to it:

```
relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/cacert.pem
smtp_use_tls = yes
```

You might have noticed that we haven’t specified our Gmail username and password in above lines. They will go into a different file. Open/Create:

```
$ sudo -H gedit /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
```

And add following line:

```
[smtp.gmail.com]:587    USERMAIL@gmail.com:PASSWORD
```

If you want to use your Google App’s domain, please replace **@gmail.com** with your **@domain.com**.

Fix permission and update postfix config to use sasl_passwd file:

```
$ sudo chmod 400 /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
$ sudo postmap /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
```

Next, validate certificates to avoid running into error. Just run following command:

```
$ cat /etc/ssl/certs/Thawte_Premium_Server_CA.pem | sudo tee -a /etc/postfix/cacert.pem
```

Finally, reload postfix config for changes to take effect:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/postfix reload
```

### Testing

#### Check if mails are sent via Gmail SMTP server

If you have configured everything correctly, following command should generate a test mail from your server to your mailbox.

```
echo "Test mail from postfix" | mail -s "Test Postfix" you@example.com
```

To further verify, if mail sent from above command is actually sent via Gmail’s SMTP server, you can log into Gmail account USERNAME@gmail.com with PASSWORD and check "***Sent Mail***" folder in that Gmail account. By default, Gmail always keeps a copy of mail being sent through its web-interface as well as SMTP server. This logging is one strong reason that we often use Gmail when mail delivery is critical.

### Troubleshooting

#### Error: "SASL authentication failed; server smtp.gmail.com"

You need to unlock the captcha by visiting this page
https://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

You can run test again after unlocking captcha.

[source](https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/linux/ubuntu-postfix-gmail-smtp/)

---

You need to use following syntax of `mail` and `mutt` to send emails, note that if you want to send attachment file via `mail` command it's not support or it's better I say I can not send my attached file via `mail` command, instead you can use `mutt` command line, it's very useful. and in `mutt` command you have to type attachment arguments after the email address. I test it and works fine.

you can install `mutt` via this command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install mutt
```

**Using `mail`**

```
mail -s "TestSubject" nospam@gmail.com -a "UserReport.txt"  < MessageBody.txt
```

**Using `mutt`**

```
mutt -s "TestSubject" nospam@gmail.com -a "UserReport.txt"  < MessageBody.txt
```

While `UserReport.txt` is your attachment file, `MessageBody` is text/file of your body of email, `TestSubject` is your email subject.

`-s` flag is used for "Subject" and `-a` flag is used for "Attachment file"

Comment: I get an invalid head error

Comment: While this answers how to send email from the commandline, the (obvious) problem of the user is: Why doesn't the recipient get the email?

Comment: I appreciate the effort you put in this answer, but: How can you be sure that @Roboman1723 wants to use GMail as an MTA? Perhaps he / she is behind a firewall in a corporate environment and would need to use $company's MTA?

IMHO we really need Roboman1723 to give detailed feedback before recommending something,

Comment: `sudo: /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd: command not found` !

Comment: +1 for the note about CAPTCHA, this is the first tutorial I've seen that listed, and was exactly my problem for the past 2 hours

Comment: @Roboman1723 -a is for append attachment for adding an attach use -A

Comment: cat: /etc/ssl/certs/Thawte_Premium_Server_CA.pem: No such file or directory

Answer (score 3):

***UPDATED MANY YEARS LATER***: Working on Ubuntu 16

1. Allow "less secure apps" to connect to your Gmail by following this link:

   ```
   https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps?pli=1
   ```
2. Run the following commands:

   ```
   sudo update-ca-certificates
   sudo apt-get install msmtp-mta
   nano ~/.msmtprc
   ```
3. Set the following msmtp config (replace yourMail@gmail.com, yourUsername and yourPassword):

   ```
   account gmail
   auth on
   host smtp.gmail.com
   port 587
   auth on
   tls on
   tls_trust_file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
   from yourMail@gmail.com
   user yourUsername
   password yourPassword

   account default : gmail
   ```
4. Config mail to use msmtp:

   ```
   nano ~/.mailrc
   ```
5. Paste this:

   ```
   set sendmail="/usr/bin/msmtp"
   ```
6. Finally send your mail (replace mail@server.com):

   ```
   echo hello | mail -s test mail@server.com
   ```
7. Alternative you can use "mailx" to even send attachments easily:

   ```
   echo "mail body" | mailx -a /path/to/your/file.doc -s "mail subject" mail@server.com
   ```

Comment: It gave error after sendimg mail  `msmtp: no recipients found
Sending data to /usr/bin/msmtp failed: Process exited with a non-zero status
cannot send message: Process exited with a non-zero status
`

Comment: "Equifax_Secure_CA"... Yeah, that aged well.

Comment: Why do you paste the above two lines into ~/.mailrc? msmtp-mta already creates a symlink from /usr/sbin/sendmail to /usr/bin/msmtp and "-a gmail" is not necessary since you already delared it as the default ("account default : gmail")? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Your line could look in shortest way like in this little shell-script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat email.txt && sendmail user@example.com < /tmp/email.txt
```