# How can I receive email from gmail in the terminal?

Tags: email, postfix, gmail, imap

I followed [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/a/522434/628749) to install postfix and set it up to send mail through Gmail, and everything works great. But it would be really nice to also receive mail automatically and be able to read it with the `mail` command. How can I do this?

Comment: Check this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MuttAndGmail and this https://kmandla.wordpress.com/2009/02/12/in-the-end-alpine-was-just-easier/