# Apt-get removed a few packages dealing with mailutils, ended up removing a lot of other packages, what happened?

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management

So I was attempting to write a bash script to take a screen shot and send an email with the screenshot. I had found [this SO answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/522434/137909) and followed the commands. In the end I could not get `mail` to work for me and wanted to restart, so being a novice I decided to run

```
sudo apt-get remove postfix mailutils libsasl2-2 ca-certificates libsasl2-modules
```

And this resulted in

[image]

and just judging on the names of a few of the packages, I think I made a big mistake. I mean, I'm pretty sure it removed `gnome-terminal` even...

I am still logged on to the machine with the same terminal open and should be able to keep it open indefinitely. I assume, again from the name of the packages removed, I won't be able to boot back into the computer or open a terminal..

I know this is a really terrible question/form, but I'm not sure what else to ask or what other information to give. **How do I fix this?**

Comment: Try `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`. If you really don't have a GUI Terminal application anymore, then use CTRL+ALT+F3 to get a TTY login and CTRL+ALT+F7 (CTRL+ALT+F2 in 17.10/Wayland) to return to the GUI.

Comment: I do have the same terminal I ran the command in, but I can't open a new one.