# Cannot send mail from command line, sasl authentication error

Tags: email, postfix

I followed the instructions here [How to send an email using command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/522431/how-to-send-an-email-using-command-line), but it dont work. When I test mailing someone it return:

```
(SASL authentication failed; server smtp.gmail.com[74.125.130.109] said: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted.
```

I have unlocked captcha as suggested by the answer, still not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to 'allow less secure apps', the settings are located within Google account settings—to enable the settings please visit this link https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps.

Then, try sending email again, it should work, you can also check the recent mail log by typing:

```
tail -f /var/log/mail.log
```

Usually the email success message goes along with this line.

```
hostname postfix/smtp[2875]: F5182534OUA: to=<john@mail.com>, relay=smtp.gmail.com[74.125.130.109]:587, delay=2.8, delays=0.07/0/1.6/1.1, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent
```

If you feel uneasy allowing 'less secure apps', you can use app password—in which you can generate standalone password for postfix itself. But it requires settings up 2 step verification, refer to this link for more details.

- https://www.google.com/landing/2step/
- https://www.lifewire.com/get-a-password-to-access-gmail-by-pop-imap-2-1171882